# http directive error in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

This is how my `/home/ubuntu/project/nginx.conf` looks like:

```
http {

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      80;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /home/ubuntu/project/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        }

        location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/project/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  unix:///home/ubuntu/project/deploy/web.sock;;
            include     /home/ubuntu/project/deploy/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to start nginx, it throws me an error: `"http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf:1`

I've been reading different posts trying to fix this but with no success. I also mention that If I remove `http { }` (so leaving only the server definition), it works. What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT] forgot to say this, I built a link:

`sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/project/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file on the server almost certainly contains `include sites-enabled/*;`

include statements simply put the contents of the referenced files inline (recursively) as such the resultant config when nginx tries to start will be along the lines of:

```
# contents of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
...
http {
    ...
    # include sites-enabled/*;

    # contents of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf
    http { # <----------------------   

        # configuration of the server
        server {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

## What am I doing wrong?

The [http directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#http) can only be in the main context (i.e. not inside any other directives) it cannot be inside another http directive hence the config described in the question is a fatal error. Removing the duplicate http directive results in a valid config, allowing nginx to start.

Comment: Right, I was dazzled by the paths. Didn't know there is a ``/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`` file

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the server block from the nginx.conf and create a new file in sites-available folder.

Thereafter, remove the link you've created and create a link to the newly created file in the sites-available folder.

For now, try removing the link and check