# Docker environment with nginx and worker_processes

Tags: php, docker, nginx, configuration

I am trying to add worker_processes into my nginx.conf file on my docker-environment, but whenever I try, it fails to restart or load. I believe I'm missing some key concept here- anyway:

This is my nginx.conf file (everything works here):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/src;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
        rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
    }
}
```

I have tried to add the following below the server brackets, but that results in nginx not loading. The error from enginx is is: **"worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1
:**

```
worker_processes: 8;

    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        etc. etc. etc.
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

And this is currently my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.15-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath g
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

Comment: Just a side note: instead of `apt-get install` and `docker-php-ext-install` what about using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your config located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` is likely being imported by the default configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with the statement `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`.

As such your config lives within the http context, which does not allow the `worker_processes` directive. You need to edit the existing statement that should already be defined in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, by default it should be set to `worker_processes auto;`.

Note: There is no colon required so just change this to `worker_processes 8;`

An answer for the same root problem is https://stackoverflow.com/a/41681414/11296166